# opening file from text wrangler to terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm sure this is a very basic question, but I'm just beginning to learn programming and I've gotten to a lesson where I have to create a file in text wrangler, save it to the desktop (called test.txt) and then copy it into the terminal. I then have to use the "less" command to view the file. How do I get that file from my desktop into the command line? and I'm using a mac fyi..

Answer (score 1):

Open up `Terminal`.

Your Desktop is at `~/Desktop` (the `~` is a shortcut for your home folder) so `cd ~/Desktop`<kbd>return</kbd> to go there then `less test.txt`<kbd>return</kbd>

By the way, if you are going to use `TextWrangler` and `Terminal` you might want to visit http://www.barebones.com/support/textwrangler/ and download the TextWrangler command line tools which allow you to open a file in TextWrangler from the command line, among other things.

Comment: Awesome..it worked, thank you very much! and I will get the command line tool, thanks again.